# How to connect or login with Odoo using c# code? And after connect with Odoo how to add custom field to Odoo database from c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-11

I have to implement some code in c# for login with Odoo database and give the logged user id please have a look,

```
public interface IOpenErpLogin
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("login")]
    int login(string dbName, string dbUser, string dbPwd);
}
```

But, it give error like "Bad Request".
Also i'm not sure for `XmlRpcUrl`, have you any idea about what URL in to `[XmlRpcUrl("")]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IOpenErpLogin : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("login")]
    int login(string dbName, string dbUser, string dbPwd);
}
```